# Getting System32 folder location with java

Tags: java, system32

On XP and above, my System32 folder is at C:\WINDOWS\system32. On Windows 2000 it is at C:\WINNT\system32. Is there a

```
System.getProperty("something");
```

or some way that I can get the location of the System32 folder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since I think NT, the way to get it through environment variables is: `%WINDIR%\system32`

You can do this:

```
String sysdir = System.getenv("WINDIR") + "\\system32";
```

More default environment variables for windows on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Examples_from_Microsoft_Windows

`SYSTEMROOT` and `WINDIR` are identical in NT systems, but `WINDIR` also works for older, 9x kernel-based windows.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
String system32Path = System.getenv("SystemRoot") + "\\system32";
```

On my installation of Windows XP, typing `set SystemRoot` in a Command Prompt returns C:\Windows

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable SYSTEMROOT will give you the location of the windows install point (something like 'C:\Windows'). Construction of the full path to the System32 directory is of course, simple ('C:\Windows\System32').